# How to set icon and text inline in mat-list-option Angular 5 Material Design

Tags: angular, material-design

```
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedContactTypes" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let ct of contacttypes" [checkboxPosition]="before" [value]="ct.id+'_'+ct.description">
                        <mat-icon matListIcon>perm_contact_calendar</mat-icon>
                        {{ct.description}}
                    </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In this case, wrapping them on a `div` will do the job:

```
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedContactTypes" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let ct of contacttypes" [checkboxPosition]="before" [value]="ct.id+'_'+ct.description">
        <div>
            <mat-icon matListIcon>perm_contact_calendar</mat-icon>
            {{ct.description}}
        </div>
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**Update**

And, if you wanna center them vertically, apply `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to the `div`

```
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedContactTypes" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let ct of contacttypes" [checkboxPosition]="before" [value]="ct.id+'_'+ct.description">
        <div class="center-vertically">
            <mat-icon matListIcon>perm_contact_calendar</mat-icon>
            {{ct.description}}
        </div>
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

CSS:

```
.center-vertically{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Stop suggesting flex-box until atleast 2022 thank you!

Comment: @Plixxer, it's fine for an intranet app

Comment: Why would you not use flex?